# Rating plugin not working on Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I followed this tutorial: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-rate/

I'm using the second approach but I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of
>   undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
>       at Function.Locales.getLocale (http://192.168.1.2:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-apprate/www/locales.js:53:74)
>       at showDialog (http://192.168.1.2:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-apprate/www/AppRate.js:91:29)
>       at Function.AppRate.promptForRating (http://192.168.1.2:8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-apprate/www/AppRate.js:203:7)
>       at callCordovaPlugin (http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/vendor.js:77234:43)
>       at http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/vendor.js:77260:28
>       at http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/vendor.js:58635:17
>       at new t (http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20886)
>       at tryNativePromise (http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/vendor.js:58634:20)
>       at getPromise (http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/vendor.js:58642:12)
>       at wrapPromise (http://192.168.1.2:8100/build/vendor.js:77243:78)

If I remove this line I don't trigger the rating but nothing else fails:
`this.appRate.promptForRating(true);`

This is the plugin that I'm using:
https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate

Comment: not sure if you opened this, but there is a [bug reported](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate/issues/184) in github

Comment: Yes, that's me. But no one answer on the repo  :(

Comment: I'll update both questions with the answer anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine. I got this [**from here**](https://ionicacademy.com/rate-my-app-ionic/).

```
import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, private appRate: AppRate, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      this.appRate.preferences = {
        openStoreInApp: false,
        displayAppName: 'Simons App',
        usesUntilPrompt: 2,
        promptAgainForEachNewVersion: false,
        storeAppURL: {
          ios: '1216856883',
          android: 'market://details?id=com.devdactic.crossingnumbers'
        },
        customLocale: {
          title: 'Do you enjoy %@?',
          message: 'If you enjoy using %@, would you mind taking a moment to rate it? Thanks so much!',
          cancelButtonLabel: 'No, Thanks',
          laterButtonLabel: 'Remind Me Later',
          rateButtonLabel: 'Rate It Now'
        },
        callbacks: {
          onRateDialogShow: function(callback){
            console.log('rate dialog shown!');
          },
          onButtonClicked: function(buttonIndex){
            console.log('Selected index: -> ' + buttonIndex);
          }
        }
      };

      // Opens the rating immediately no matter what preferences you set
      this.appRate.promptForRating(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm Erperejildo (https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate/issues/184#issuecomment-343486808)   
:D

Comment: Yes, I know. I have found this tutorial using your deleted answer where you put here in `11 Nov 2017 at 20:22`. Thanks a lot for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and I was able to see the popup dialog after adding this line;

> useLanguage: 'en',

Another error appeared which was easy to fix using the callback function below;

```
  callbacks: {
    onButtonClicked: function (buttonIndex) {
      console.log("onButtonClicked -> " + buttonIndex);
    }
```